# How to select rows that date is in range from ranges table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table1 that hold ranges

```
rangeId, rangeName, fromDate, toDate,cat
```

another table2 has rows

```
rowTitle,rowDate
```

I need to

```
select  all rows
from table2
that table2.rowDate is between table1.fromDate
                           and table1.toDate
and cat = 1
```

Comment: What did you try? What did you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like :

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
join table1 t1 on t2.rowdate between t1.fromDate and t1.toDate
where t1.cat = 1
```

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list

Comment: @Michael * doesn't bother me too much since columns are not mentioned in the question. Something such as `...` would have been better though. What bother me here is the data comparaison using between. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries   A better choice is t2.rowdate >= t1.fromDate and t2.rowDate < t1.toDate (using <, <=, >=, > whether it is inclusive or exlusive ranges)